# What is the relation between Azure devops repos and TFVC, and where is the option to choose between GIT and TFVC?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, tfvc

I know that azure devops has 2 offerings - 1) cloud based; 2) on-prem azure devops server

I am using clous based azure devops repos which is using GIT in the background. GIT is decentralized.

Previously, before using azure devops I used on-premise TFS (team foundation server) which is centralized source control.

Today I came across a person who is using azure devops with tfvc (and not GIT). So I am curious to know:

1. Where in azure repos is the option to choose between TFVC vs GIT?
2. Does using TFVC require any additional installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are creating a new project you can choose which version control you want to use, you can choose TFVC and using Azure Repos with TFVS version control:

[image]

Comment: So the azure repo will configure GIT or TFVC (based on the drop-down selection) in the background and manage it as a SAAS (software as a service)? Or do I need any additional installation or setup?

Comment: First option :)

Answer (score 0):

It's at the project creation that you decide which type of version control (Git or TFVC) your project will use.

But, something interesting to know, is that you could add later:

- git repositories to a TFVC project
- a TFVC collection to a git project

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/team-projects?view=azure-devops